# Computing orbits in labelled graphs

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Given a labelled graph **G = (V, E, L)**, **L** is function that maps vertices to labels. I want find subsets **S  ⊆ V** such that the mappings of vertices in **S** in all the automorphisms (should satisfy edge and label constraints) lie in the same set **S**. I am not sure if these constraints are enough to call **S** as an orbit of the graph **G**.

Are there any commonly used algorithms to compute these subsets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the nauty algorithm for the graph isomorphism problem can also be used to compute the orbits in vertex colored graphs( or labeled graphs).

[Nauty](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/nauty/implement.shtml)
[Official Nauty website](http://cs.anu.edu.au/people/bdm/nauty/)